# createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element. when test React js file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

[test error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bbW.png)

I'm using React 18.2.0 version and I am getting the error you see above. My index.test.jsx file:

```
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";
import CountryDetail from "./index";

test('Country detail renders correctly',()=>{
    render(<CountryDetail />)
    const element = screen.getByText('Corona Virus Data')
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
} )
```

And this file my App.js file:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "routes/home";
import CountryDetail from "routes/countryDetail";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={ <HomePage />}
            />
          <Route path="/:country" element={<CountryDetail />} />
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js file:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `import CountryDetail from "./index";` or `import CountryDetail from "routes/countryDetail";`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not working

Comment: _What's_ not working? My point is you seem to be importing the root React rendering file instead of the component you're actually trying to test.